# Flutter | border radius not apply on Android

Tags: android, css, flutter

I want to find out why border radius wouldn't apply top half of the widget on Android.
Here is the image on Android

[image: Android]

However on the web, it's working like image below.

[image]

Does anyone know why?

**Code**

```
    Center(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 1.5,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0))),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 250.0,
          height: 150.0,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 60.0,
                color: Colors.pink[200].withOpacity(0.95),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Felicity Jones'),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('9:15'),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: What Android device have you tried to see this on? What OS level? Have you tried  different devices?

Comment: I tried on nexus5 api26.

Comment: Try moving the SizedBox as the parent of the Card and let the Column be a direct child of the Card

Comment: @FederickJonathan I tried but not fix it

Comment: @Daibaku you may want to check my answer as well which is more efficient than trying to use another widget to resolve the issue. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you observe carefully by changing the `opacity` of the color for time being to:

`color: Colors.pink[200].withOpacity(0.2),`

You'll see that the top left and top right corners are cut-off and not filled by the color:

[image]

In order to avoid this, use `Card` widget's `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,` property that covers all corners of the card with the given color. Here's the updated result:

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** In your case like @Darshan mentioned you can just set `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias` in `Card` widget.

You can use also use `ClipRRect` to force the child to have the given border radius, if you don't have `clipBehavior`.

```
Center(
  child: Card(
    elevation: 1.5,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
    ),
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 250.0,
        height: 150.0,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 60.0,
              color: Colors.pink[200].withOpacity(0.95),
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Felicity Jones'),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('9:15'),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Instead of using another widget to resolve issue, `Card` widget has `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,` property that resolves the issue. You may check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
Center(
    child:
      Card(
          elevation: 1.5,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0))),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 250.0,
            height: 150.0,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                        top: new Radius.circular(16.0)
                        ),
                    color: Colors.pink[200].withOpacity(0.95),
                  ),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Felicity Jones'),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('9:15'),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

**Note that the color was moved inside the BoxDecoration as it will fail to compile otherwise.**
I kept the shape attribute so that the lower part of the card will be rounded as well. You could tinker with that and remove it, if necessary.

[image: Screenshot]